# C, macro arguments, substitution of parameters

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have a old code that compiles just fine (also gcc for NXP micro, can't remember which version)

```
#define TIME_CONSTANT     250,mSec

if (SysTimerOnTime(tmr, TIME_CONSTANT)) 
{

}
```

Now I tried to do the same thing for ESP8266, using gcc for Xtensa

```
xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.exe (GCC) 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am using -std=c99 (because some inline asm)

The complaint is about passing 2 parameters in SysTimerOnTime macro which takes 3. So if I use:

```
if (SysTimerOnTime(tmr, 250, mSec))
```

will work fine.

What will be the problem?

I am positive that in LpcXpresso worked perfect (also gcc) however, I can't test now since the toolchain is not installed anymore.

The macro would be like this

```
#define SysTimerOnTime(t,v,unit)    (t.Enable && (Now()-t.Value) > unit(v))
```

Seems that double indirection did the trick. Perhaps LPCXpresso used older compiler. Doesn't matter, this works, thanks Jonathan Leffler

```
#define TIME_CONSTANT     250,mSec
#define     SysTimerOnTime_(t,v,unit)   (t.Enable && (Now()-t.Value) > unit(v))
#define     SysTimerOnTimeX(x) x
#define     SysTimerOnTime(tmr, con)    SysTimerOnTimeX(SysTimerOnTime_(tmr, con))
```

Comment: ...and the definition of `SysTimerOnTime` could be relevant here...

Comment: It is not relevant, I just said that worked fine as it is. But here it is :) Must be a compiler problem or standard... I can't figure out.

Comment: See [Macro Expansion Algorithm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html).

Comment: The fact that `SysTimerOnTime` is a macro is 100% relevant to your problem.  What isn't clear is why the code used to work before.

Comment: You seem to have gotten a good answer, but in the future, when asking questions like this, please always include the _complete and unedited_ text of the error messages.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Only thing I can think is that "old" here means "pre-ANSI".  I _think_ the traditional preprocessor might have let you get away with this, at least some incarnations of it.

Comment: @zwol; I agree — either pre-standard or 'non-standard'.  I'm not sure I can work up the energy to try and find a 30-year old compiler (so it is pre-C89); it wouldn't run directly on my Mac, anyway.

Comment: guys, it's not ancient! It is offer now by NXP for their MCUs. I will install it tonight and post results here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the invocation of `SysTimerOnTime()` is being assessed, the arguments are collected before any expansion of the arguments.  There are only two arguments — so the macro is invoked incorrectly.  You'd have to introduce a level of indirection to be able to use the `TIME_CONSTANT` macro.  For example:

```
#define SysTimerOnTimeC(tmr, con) SysTimerOnTimeX(SysTimerOnTime(tmr, con))
#define SysTimerOnTimeX(x) x
```

And then you can invoke:

```
if (SysTimerOnTimeC(tmr, TIME_CONSTANT))
{
    …
}
```

The C is for 'constant'; the X is for 'expansion'.  You don't call the `SysTimerOnTimeX()` macro directly from code; it is just a helper macro.

And I can't help but feel that you'd be better off with:

```
#define QUARTER_SECOND mSec(250)
#define SysTimerOnTime(t, v)    ((t).Enable && (Now()-(t).Value) > (v))
```

and then invoking:

```
if (SysTimerOnTime(tmr, QUARTER_SECOND)) 
{
    …
}
```

I also parenthesized both arguments in the expansion here.  It's the conventional and generally sensible advice (though definitely not what's wanted in the main part of the answer).  Without the parentheses, you'd get complaints from the compiler if you ever invoked:

```
if (SysTimerOnTime(*ptr, QUARTER_SECOND))
```

because the `*` has lower-priority than the `.`.  The extra parentheses should be applied to the base `SysTimerOnTime` macro.